# Fixing PHP8 Upgrade - String on String Error

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying an upgrade to PHP8 and troubleshooting a theme that is giving a fatal error.

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string

I've narrowed it down to the section causing the problem. Commenting these lines loads the site, but of course the shortcodes display as plain text on the front-end.

Still trying to learn PHP and from searching I believe a String is getting treated like an Array is my understanding, just having troubles figuring out how to write it compatible for PHP8.

```
// get event in home sortcode
function sc_get_events_home($params){
    $showLearnMore = $params['show_learn_more'];
    $numItems = $params['post_per_page'] ? $params['post_per_page'] : 3;
    $date_now = date('Ymd');
    $args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'events',
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'order'             => 'ASC',
            'orderby'           => 'when',
            'posts_per_page'    => $numItems,
            'meta_query'        => array(   
                                        array(
                                            'key'       => 'when',
                                            'value'     =>$date_now,
                                            'compare'   =>'>=',
                                            )
                                        )   
                );
    
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $items = $query->posts;

    if(count($items) <3) { // upcoming < 3 -> get webinar resources

        // webinar newest
        $argsWbNewest   = array(
            'post_type'         => 'resources',
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'    => 1,
            'order'             => 'DESC',
            'orderby'           => 'date',
            'tax_query'         => array(
                                        array(
                                            'taxonomy'  => 'type',
                                            'field'     => 'slug',
                                            'terms'     => array('webinars'),
                                            'operator'  => 'IN',
                                            )
                                        )       
                                );

        $queryWbNewest =  new WP_Query( $argsWbNewest );
        $itemsWbNewest = $queryWbNewest->posts;
        
        wp_reset_postdata();
        // webinar newest
        $argsWbPopular = array(
            'post_type'         => 'resources',
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'    => 3,
            'meta_key'          => 'wpb_post_views_count', 
            'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
            'order'             => 'DESC'  ,
            'tax_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy'  => 'type',
                                    'field'     => 'slug',
                                    'terms'     => array('webinars'),
                                    'operator'  => 'IN',
                                    )
                                )
                            );

        $queryWbPopular = new WP_Query( $argsWbPopular );
        $itemsWbPopular = $queryWbPopular->posts;
        wp_reset_postdata();

    }
    
    ob_start();
       include 'view/sc-events-home.php';
       $data = ob_get_contents();
       
    ob_get_clean();
    return $data;
}

add_shortcode( 'get_events_home', 'sc_get_events_home' );
```

Any guidance on helping me learn the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The offset needs to be an integer, not a string I guess. That's from the error itself. Which line does it happen?

Comment: What string exactly causes a problem?

Comment: Since you're including this file view/sc-events-home.php the error could be there. You should enable wp_debug and get a specific line number.